# Turning a folder into an executable jar file in Java

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I need some help with turning a folder into an executable jar file. I want to do this in my application not from a batch file.
Basically i have a folder on my desktop with class files already in it, all i want is to turn that folder into an executable jar file.

I have already tried this:

```
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/myfolderwithclasses");
    File file2 = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/myfolderwithclasses.jar");
    file.renameTo(file2);
```

Unfortunately all this does is rename the folder to what i set but it doesn't change the file type.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a tutorial online to show you how to make jar files: [creating jar files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html).

Comment: can you tell us about your application? what it does? thats will help us to understand and help you

Comment: Basically i am having it extract the contents of a jar, then i want to be able to compile the contents of the extracted contents back into a jar file. Once i extract it i intend on adding my own files before i compile it back together again. I just need help with the compiling the folder that contains all the extracted contents with my added contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an executable JAR isn't as simple as renaming a folder. You can use IDE functionality, as has been mentioned, but a more portable solution is to use something like Apache Ant, which is actually supported in a lot of the IDEs. You'll want to use the [JAR Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html). If you just have your own classes to package, and no complicated library structure, the examples at the bottom of the page should suffice. Here's a [Hello World tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) for Ant to help you set up your build file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse and export runnable jar.

Comment: When giving answers like this, try to be more helpful. A helpful answer would explain the steps the OP would take and even cite reference material that backs up the statement.